# Getting long numbers from binary file in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a binary file from my computer in javascript. And this binary file contains some long numbers in the following:

20
56599565 6559565
65656589 6595956
26989565 5656595
...

My question is that how can I get these numbers?

I have a binary file that contains numbers, its created with serialization on c++. And the first 40 bytes of this binary file is empty. After these 40 bytes have passed, my numbers are starting to come.

My solution:

After reading the file successfully I have an ArrayBuffer right? And I know that my numbers start from the 40. bytes. So I sliced it.

```
// rawData ArrayBuffer(197283) {}
var frameCount = rawData.slice(40,48);
var frameCountView = new Float64Array(frameCount);
```

And then what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we can get the Int8Array from Arraybuffer;

```
// rawData ArrayBuffer(197283) {}
var fileContent = rawData.slice(40);
var frameCountView = new Int64Array(fileContent);
var byteArray = new BigUint64Array(fileContent);
```